# how to reach icon for xamarin menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile-application, file-structure

I have created menu in Xamarin forms for Android. I only see text, no icons:
[image]

I think I simply dont know where to put icons correctly to reach them from my menu file. I have files structure like this:

[image]

And I try to reach PatientInfo.png from FlyoutMenuPage.xaml file like this:

```
  <ListView.ItemsSource>
      <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutItemPage}">
          <local:FlyoutItemPage Title="Mano duomenys" IconSource="PatientInfo.png" TargetPage="{x:Type local:PatientInfo}"/>
      </x:Array>
  </ListView.ItemsSource>
```

Where to put my icons (which folder) and how to reach them?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I wasnt able to find that. I am new to mobile development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images should be added in the `Resources/drawable` directory.

You can refer to the article about [How to set the local image.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)